# Removing only zero rows after shuffling a data.frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to resample (with replacement) a data.frame several times. This data frame is a species by site matrix. There are several zeros in this data, which means that the resampling procedure sometimes produce only zero rows. Thus, I'd like to eliminate matrices with only zero rows from each for loop, because the function multipart (vegan package) did not accept these matrices.

[please, download data here](http://bit.ly/1M5aEfX)

Thank you all in advance.

```
require(vegan)

# DATA (Edited)

dat <- read.table("df.stack.txt", h=T) # Link above
mat <- dat[,c(-1, -2, -3)]
levels <- dat[,1:3]

## Vectors for saving desired statistics
alfa.null <- NULL
beta1.null <- NULL
beta2.null <- NULL

## Shuffling matrices ## Here is the problem

times <- 99
for (i in times) {
mat.rand <- sample(mat, replace=TRUE) ### Problem to be solved - some matrices will have only zero rows 
div.aleat <- multipart(mat.rand ~ ., levels, index="renyi", scales=1, nsimul=99, global=TRUE)
alfa.null[i] <- div.aleat$statistic[[1]]
beta1.null[i] <- div.aleat$statistic[[4]]
beta2.null[i] <- div.aleat$statistic[[5]]
}
```

Comment: If your matrix is named `mat` you could do `mat[apply(mat, 1, function(x) {!all(x==0)}),]`.

Comment: Thank you @eipi10. But I cannot remove any row. I need, actually, to start another loop every time a random matrix has any only zero row. Thus, the 99 matrices created must have only `TRUE` values when I run `rowSums(mat.rand) > 0`.

Comment: I think the problem is that multipart will raise that error if there are *any* rows will all zeros.   To sample from just the nonzero rows, you can just replace `sample(df, replace=TRUE,)` with `sample(df[(rowSums(mat.rand)!=0),],size=nrow(df), replace=TRUE,)` in your original code.  (the `size=nrow(df)` is optional in case you want the original dimension to be the same)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to keep resampling until you get a nonzero matrix like so:

```
times <- 99
for (i in seq.int(times)) {
    while(TRUE){
        mat.rand <- sample(df, replace=TRUE) ### Problem to be solved - some matrices will have only zero rows 
        if(any(rowSums(mat.rand)!=0))
            break
    }

    blah blah blah
}
```

Of course with a `while(TRUE)` loop, it's a good idea to catch infinite loops like so:

```
times <- 99
max_Tries <- 100
for (i in seq.int(times)) {
    tries = 0
    while(TRUE){
        mat.rand <- sample(df, replace=TRUE) ### Problem to be solved - some matrices will have only zero rows 
        if(any(rowSums(mat.rand)!=0))
            break
        tries <- tries + 1
        if(tries > max_Tries)
            stop("number of tries exceeded max_Tries: possible infinite loop")
    }

    blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jthorpe. I believe that  `if(any(mat.rand!=0))` should be `if(any(rowSums(mat.rand)!=0))`, because the problem of `multipart` is sites (that are rows) with no species (only zeros).

Comment: I updated the code to reflect your suggestion.  Incidentally, I didn't have the function `cutter` so i wan't able to run your full example...

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems that the code did not stopped when rowSums==0 in some rows. I have uploaded my data (link in the main text) to remove cutter` function. I believe you can now fully run this example